# Open Certificate Information from Web Browser Control

Tags: c#, .net, browser, ssl-certificate

Does anyone know how to open up the "Certificate Information" screen based on the SSL from the `WebBrowser` control?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be achieved by using a class called `X509Certificate2UI`.

To make this class avalable to you, you need to add a reference to `System.Security.dll`

In the `X509Certificate2UI` class you have a meyhod called `DisplayCertificate()` which takes an `X509Certificate2` object as a parameter. When invoked, this method shows a dialog box displaying all cert information including chaining, exactly the same as the dialog box you will find in IE.

The webbrowser control can only return a `X509Certificate` which can then be passed into the constructor of the `X509Certificate2` class.

So the code looks as such:

```
//includes on top
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

//Do webrequest to get info on secure site
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://securesite.com");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
response.Close();

//retrieve the ssl cert and assign it to an X509Certificate object
X509Certificate cert = request.ServicePoint.Certificate;

//convert the X509Certificate to an X509Certificate2 object by passing it into the constructor
X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert);

//display the cert dialog box
X509Certificate2UI.DisplayCertificate(cert2);
```

Comment: @Kyle, I'm getting a exception at the line `request.ServicePoint.Certificate` .   An Platform Not Supported Exception is being thrown when trying to access `request.ServicePoint`.  Any idea why I'm unable to access the server certificate ?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct you should search for this information not in `WebBrowser` but inside of CryptoAPI. Exist such function like  `CryptUIDlgSelectCertificateFromStore`, `CryptUIDlgViewContext` from **Cryptui.dll**. There are some functions in **WINTRUST.DLL** like `WinVerifyTrustEx` which can also display some dialogs.

Could you exactly describe how I can display dialog what you want in Internet Explore? Do you works already with `WebBrowser` control, then you can trace, for example, inside of `BeforeNavigate2` Event the url which Internet Explorer has. Having this URL you can download SSL certificate an display if with respect of `CryptUIDlgViewContext`. To download or get the certificate you can use InternetQueryOption with INTERNET_OPTION_SERVER_CERT_CHAIN_CONTEXT or INTERNET_OPTION_CLIENT_CERT_CONTEXT flag. It can be that information from INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_CERTIFICATE, INTERNET_OPTION_SECURITY_CERTIFICATE_STRUCT, (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251347) will be enough for you.

Comment: @Oleg - Thanks for the interesting information, but this information is all attainable from a `X509Certificate` by using a `HttpWebRequest`. +1 Though.

Answer (score 1):

While it's not using the .NET WebBrowser, you could leverage this C# wrapper code against the standard WebBrowser without much impact on your project:

http://code.google.com/p/csexwb2/

It will then require you only to say `ShowCertificateDialog()`

There is no way to do an ExecWB or invoke that dialog otherwise.

Comment: @Nissan - Thanks for this, I can't use it currently but it adds an "easy" to implement solution.

Comment: I looked and looked for ways to call Exec and bring up the dialog with the native .NET control using ActiveXInstance but never had any success.  I wish you luck on this going forward.

Comment: Have a look at the new accepted answer. It might give you some joy later on.

Comment: So glad you found a definitive answer to this.