# C# Fetching server certificates from HTTPS URL throws System.PlatformNotSupportedException exception

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I'm using the below code snippet in order to fetch (or obtain) the certificates from a HTTPS URL website in C#.

A similar code is being posted over here -> [Open Certificate Information from Web Browser Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690082/open-certificate-information-from-web-browser-control) and [C# Download all https certificates from a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999494/c-sharp-download-all-https-certificates-from-a-website?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
 but nothing is helping me and I keep getting the exception at below  line #

```
           X509Certificate cert = request.ServicePoint.Certificate;
```

***Exception :***

```
   System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'
```

**CODE :**

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String sslServerHost = "https://docs.genesys.com/Documentation"
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create( sslServerHost);
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        response.Close();


       X509Certificate cert = request.ServicePoint.Certificate;

        //convert the X509Certificate to an X509Certificate2 object by passing it into the constructor
       X509Certificate2 cert2 = new X509Certificate2(cert);

        X509Store userCaStore = new X509Store(storeName: StoreName.Root, storeLocation: StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        try
        {
            userCaStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
            userCaStore.Add(cert2);

            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Debug.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
            Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }

    }
```

**UPDATE**

The `ServicePoint.Certificate` is not supported in .NET Core projects and so I had tried using the Server Certificate validation callback using the below code :

```
request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, validatedCert, chain, 
errors) => { X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate2(validatedCert); 
Console.WriteLine("Inside callback" + cert); return errors == 
System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None; }
```

The above callback doesn't seem to be invoked. Can any of you please tell when would the above callback gets executed.

Moreover, I'm not getting any exception when trying to connect to HTTPS URL without adding the server certificate to trust store.  Can anyone please let me know why we are not getting any exception (in .NET application) when trying to access the HTTPS URL given that I have not ignored the certificate validation.

Comment: @mjwills, Thanks for pointing out.  I have updated the question with the details of exception !

Comment: Does Googling for `request.ServicePoint.Certificate PlatformNotSupportedException` help (e.g. https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/25816)?

Comment: @mjwills: Yes, I had tried printing console logs inside the callback `ServerCertificateValidationCallback`. The certificate details are NOT getting displayed in the console which means that the callback is not getting triggered.

Comment: Is your code still calling `request.ServicePoint.Certificate;`? Are you running on .NET Core or .NET Framework?

Comment: @mjwills : I'm running on .NET Core . I had removed the line `request.ServicePoint.Certificate;` and replaced it with the callback 
 .......................... .................................... `request.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, validatedCert, chain, errors) =>
            {
                X509Certificate cert = new X509Certificate2(validatedCert);
                Console.WriteLine("Inside callback"+cert);
                return errors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None;
            };`

Comment: @mjwills: I have updated my question. Could you please review it.  In addition to that, I am not getting any exceptions when trying to connect to HTTPS URL given that neither I have not added the server certificate to the windows certificate store nor I have ignored the certificate validation mechanism !!

Answer (score 0):

Using legacy HttpWebRequest on .Net core is looking for trouble.
You should switch to HttpClient and set the [callback](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/c6efb248fd3c633e09733b2c9514d5729577a701/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClientHandler.Windows.cs#L383) on a HttpClientHandler instance.

```
  var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
  handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (request,cert,chain,error) => true;
  var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```